# Checkin policy to make comments mandatory

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I would like to implement the Checkin policy so that comments while check-in the file should be made mandatory. Please let me know, how can I do this in TFS SDK in VS2010.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Amit

Answer (score 3):

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=tfs%20mandatory%20checkin%20comments&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) pulls up [this site](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/08/tfs-2010-how-to-force-comments-when.html) (for TFS 2010).

For reference (from the site, not mine):

1. Find “Team Project Settings”
2. “Source Control…”
3. Enter Check-in Policy tab
4. Add…
5. Select “Changeset Comments Policy”
6. OK

**Edit:**
Apparently you need [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) installed (for all developers) for this to work.